# Include mentoring Junior developers and interns in my resume?

Tags: interviewing, resume, job-search, new-job, mentoring

I am a Software Engineer with 4 years experience and I was updating my resume recently. A good part of my current work as a Software Engineer involves mentoring a junior engineer and 2 interns.

Do I include this information in my resume? How is it looked upon my Recruiters and probably hiring manager if added?

Comment: I don't think it would ever hurt, but its pretty much just assumed you mentor lower skilled programmers.  I'm not sure I'd bother adding it unless you were doing something out of the ordinary.

Comment: Why would you not? It's a (presumably) significant part of your current job and it demonstrates your ability to handle senior responsibilities.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I include this information in my resume?

You should include it *if* you are applying to a company or job where that mentoring experience would be valuable.

Otherwise, you should leave it outside if you are applying to somewhere mentoring is not a valuable asset they are looking in their recruits.

Remember, resumes can and should be taylored to fit the job you seek, so what goes inside a resume strongly depends on what company an position you are applying.

> How is it looked upon my Recruiters and probably hiring manager if added?

Again, depends on where are you applying, so be careful not to include it just to make your resume look longer or "better".

However, in general I consider mentoring is a quality that is always regarded as useful in any company, as it indicates you are able to pass your knowledge to your coworkers and delegates efficiently.

Some management or senior positions definitely require the candidate to be able to teach and effectively convey their ideas to others, so it is a skill you *may* consider including if it is appropriate for this job.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, absolutely put your mentoring in your resume. But as GrayCygnus noted how you do your resume for a particular job application depends on the situation. You really should tailor your resume to best fit whatever position you're applying for. In any case, showing that you have good communication skills is a big positive. Positions in which you are the lone cowboy are none existent these days.